# Can I debug node in gdb without new xterm?

Tags: ros, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [this](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) tutorial is shown how to launch nodes in gdb (and other tools). There are two options for gdb.

- launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args" :
  run your node in a gdb in a separate
  xterm window, manually type run to
  start it
- launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args" :
  run your node in gdb in the same
  xterm as your launch without having
  to type run to start it

Is it possible to run my node in gdb in the same xterm as my launch with having to manually type run to start it? My attempts to do that were unsuccessful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201989/can-i-debug-node-in-gdb-without-new-xterm?/) by [Matthew.J](https://answers.ros.org/users/21406/matthew.j/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2015-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-29**:
Isn't the second option you list what you ask?

**Comment by [Matthew.J](https://answers.ros.org/users/21406/matthew.j/) on 2015-01-29**:
Nope :-( it automatically runs the node. I want to set breakpoint and som awatches first. And when I remove the run command gdb doesn't launch correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems I misread what you wanted.

> Is it possible to run my node in gdb in the same xterm as my launch **with having to manually type run to start it**?

I initially thought you wanted *with-**out** having to manually type run ..*, hence my confusion.

According to [Debugging with GDB - File Options - 2.1.1 Choosing Files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/File-Options.html#File-Options):

> -ex command
>
> Execute a single gdb command.

You tried `gdb -ex run --args`. I would assume `gdb --args` should do what you want (ie: start gdb with the specified executable, but not run it).

---

Edit: btw, I've assumed you want to start your node(s) using launch files. That is obviously not required, you could just as well start the node you want to debug with `gdb --args /path/to/node/binary ARGS`. But that would be in a separate terminal, so may not be what you want.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matthew.J](https://answers.ros.org/users/21406/matthew.j/) on 2015-01-29**:
Great but there is still one problem. When I run it with `gdb --args` I can't see what I'm writing in terminal. It's hidden like a password.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-29**:
You probably need to add `output="screen"` to the `node` element (in your launch file) of the node that you want to debug.

**Comment by [Matthew.J](https://answers.ros.org/users/21406/matthew.j/) on 2015-01-29**:
Yes that was it. THX